# Деепричастный оборот с союзным словом

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, союзы, деепричастный-оборот, деепричастия

Добрый вечер!

Листал учебник по русскому языку для пятого класса. Встретил такое предложение:

> В языке нет хаоса, всё в нём подчиняется языковым закономерностям,
>   изучая которые**_** учёные выводят правила.

Нужна ли запятая после слова ***которые***? Авторы считают, что нет. Я рассуждаю так: это простой деепричастный оборот, в котором дополнение выражено относительным местоимением ***которые***, — а значит, по общим правилам запятая нужна.

Или всё-таки нет? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая не нужна - деепричастный оборот разрывается союзным словом (а не   относительным местоимением) *который,* входящим в состав придаточного предложения.

Союзные слова - знаменательные части речи, они являются членами придаточного предложения. *(Которые = закономерности.)*

[**Правило**](https://www.tutoronline.ru/blog/kogda-deeprichastnyj-oborot-ne-obosobljaetsja) (из которого нас интересует лишь один пункт, четвёртый):

Запятые не ставятся, если

> деепричастный оборот разрывается словом, входящим в состав
>   придаточного предложения либо в состав простого предложения. Обычно
>   это касается придаточных определительных предложений с союзным словом
>   *который*.
>
> Например:
>
> *Налево была дверь, выйдя через которую возможно было попасть в гримерную.*
>
> *Вчера вышел на экран новый фильм Джима Джармуша, посмотрев который нетрудно понять его творческий рост.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

В языке нет хаоса, всё в нём подчиняется языковым закономерностям, изучая которые[ ] учёные выводят правила.
Деепричастный оборот разрывается союзным словом (а не относительным местоимением) который, входящим в состав придаточного предложения...Союзные слова - знаменательные части речи..
Интересно, какие именно? Но здесь действительно работает правило постановки знаков препинания в СПП с придаточным определительным(есть главное: "всё в нём подчиняется языковым закономерностям" КАКИМ? и есть придаточное "изучая которые  учёные выводят правила.", когда запятая не ставится сразу ПЕРЕД союзным словом "который" и сразу "ПОСЛЕ" него.